# How can I connect to AWS machines with ease from my laptop?

Tags: knife

I need to connect to aws servers but have hard time figuring out the IP or the ssh key.  Is there a way i can use to easly connect ?

I would like a tool that will help me connect to the machines.

Comment: will this help: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/aws-ec2-part-2-ssh-into-ec2-instance-c7879d47b6b2

Answer (score 0):

The DevOps have developed a tool to use with knife.

https://github.com/bluevine-dev/system/tree/master/misc/scripts/knife-con

Knife plugin which allows an elastic and easy-to-use interface to manage SSH connections to AWS EC2 instances and Chef nodes from within the same scope.

Some features of knife-con:

Dynamic Chef environments and AWS accounts manipulation with one, easy to understand and single config
Supports in-depth search of Chef node attributes - based on your needs
Dynamic search use cases: you can choose whater to use the combined interface (Chef and AWS), only AWS, or only Chef
Parallel SSH support on search results - you can pass a single shell command to the search results
Fast and easy search results selection with a beautiful UI
Automatic VPN switching - multi platform support (OPENVPN, TUNNELBLICK)
How the plugin works?
The plugin accepts multiple options such as regular expressions or Chef role patterns - during the search phase the plugin will prefer to grab it's results from a node search on the server - It will attempt to locate nodes which have checked-in during a pre-set healthy period - the default healthy period which can be overwritten is 24 hours. If no results are returned from the server, the plugin will attempt to locate AWS instances based on the search pattern. The plugin offers an easy to use and understandable interface to manage nodes and instances results - which will allow you to choose the relevant node or instance result and establish an SSH session from within your local machine.